# Copying only files without extension via scp

Tags: ssh, scp

I have a strange situation that I need to solve. In a server I have several files stored, which are named:

Area01 Area01.hst Area01.rst ... Area02 Area02.hst Area02.rst ... etc.

With some other files in there too. In order to retrieve those files, I would generally use

`scp server:~/Area* location/in/my/computer`.

The problem is, what if I only need to retrieve the files AreaXX (without extension)?

The only solution I can figure out is assigning an extension to those files and then retrieve them using

`scp server:~/Area*.newextension location/in/my/computer`

Any other ideas?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What about `scp server:~/Area?? /location/to/your/computer`

This should find any instance of "Area" followed by any two characters "??"

Comment: The bash glob for two arbitrary characters is `??` not `..`

Comment: Thank you! I think it was a basic wildcard question but I'm glad I have the answer.

Answer (score 1):

```
scp server:~/Area?? location/in/my/computer
```

will get you all files named "Area__", as "?" globs for a single char.